# Using component outside main class

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Is there a way to use component created in main class(which extends `JFrame`) outside that class? I am using netbeans generator and I want to: `textArea.setText("")`
but I don't have access to that textArea component outside main class

Comment: What exactly is the second class?

Comment: ok :D how can i do it?

Comment: second class extends JPanel and implements MouseListener...so when mouse is clicked i want to textArea.setText("")

Comment: What is it you want to achieve? Why do you need access to the text area?

Comment: @mkkrolik FYI...you can modify in Component objects in NetBeans, just make your `JTextField` public and access it from any class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide a getter to access the text area:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
// ...

public class Main extends JFrame {
    private JTextArea textArea;

    private void createUI() {
        // ...
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        // ...
    }

    public JTextArea getTextArea() {
        return textArea;
    }
}

public class Other {
    // ...
    public void update(Main main, String message) {
        main.getTextArea().setText(message);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I still think it is a better idea to have the `Main` class pass the `JTextArea` into the `Other` class; this way, it is easier to control who has access to the text area.

Comment: That's a good point. We haven't been told anything about how or when the other class is created, though, so I didn't want to make any assumptions.

Comment: You should avoid exposing the textarea itself  as it gives callers direct access to the parent component, allows callers to do things to it that you really don't want them to  like remove it or all the child components of the parent component

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple ways of doing this. One is having public access to the object (not recommended):

```
public JTextArea textArea; //when you declare the object
```

But I recommend providing a method in the main class such as:

```
public void clearTextArea(){
    textArea.setText("");
}
```

This is usually the best because you provide minimum access to the component; you can ensure that the main class is the class that handles the component, and none else.

Or you could make a constructor in your `MouseListener` class that takes the text area as a parameter:

```
private JTextArea textArea;

public MyMouseListener(JTextArea toChangeOnAction){
    textArea = toChangeOnAction;
}
```

This way is much easier when you want to use many methods from the text area, rather than having to create many methods in the main class.

Comment: @MadProgrammer You mean the context: "provide a method in the main class"?

Comment: No, sorry, the OP's question lacks context, so it's hard to know what solution would solve their problem

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `JTextFeild` to the second class's constructor.

```
public class MainClass {
    private JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    private SecondClass secondClass;

    public MainClass() {
        secondClass = new SecondClass(textField);
    }
}

public class SecondClass {
    private JTextField textField;

    public SecondClass(JTextField textField) {
        this.textField = textField;
    }
}
```

Now that same text field from the `MainClass` can be used in the `SecondClass` because it is being passed by reference

---

Also see [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21075014/2587435) for an example

Comment: Nitpick: this exposes the component to misuse, including access to the parent component, allowing the caller to do nasty things to do only the text area by the parent component. While the visitor pattern isn't a better idea more context of what the OP is trying to achieve would help determine if this approach is the best approach - IMHO ;)

Answer (score -2):

In the main class make sure you have set:

```
public static JTextArea textArea;
```

and then you can do:

```
MainClass.textArea.setText("");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i can't do it, because i use netbeans generator and i can't modify component objects